# Is there something similar to "Set Next Statement" available in Visual Studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Usually while debugging C++ code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 I find the "Set Next Statement" very useful. Wanted to check if something similar to "Set Next Statement" is also available in Visual Studio code debugger while debugging a Node js application where I can change the statement where I want my next execution to begin during debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this feature is available under the name "Jump to Cursor":

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_jump-to-cursor

It will become available as an "Set next statement" alias:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9947#issuecomment-610631969

<s>As of now,</s>

> No.

This is a much-requested feature,

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12514
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1025

and some work with that aim has been done already:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvsd/issues/18
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/issues/28

But the feature is not available yet in VS Code.

Comment: I almost always want to "time travel" backwards with this feature in Visual Studio proper. Does going backwards work?

Comment: @TreyMack moving the program counter backwards, yes. Changing variables to values they had earlier, no.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with [VSCode v1.47, June 2020](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/4762c7285c385d1ebd5076b5414a7874117c48aa/release-notes/v1_47.md#new-command-alias-set-next-statement-for-jump-to-cursor), following [issue 92585](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92585),

> We have added an "alias" for the Jump to Cursor command.
> **The alias is "Set Next Statement'.**
> So now it should be available in the command palette.

See [commit fb28ced](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/fb28cedc37fcdd589f6a7d35ef093f324d649a3c).

> ### New command alias `Set Next Statement` for Jump to Cursor
>
> To make the command Jump to Cursor more discoverable for users coming from Visual Studio, we've added the command alias `Set Next Statement`.
>
> If you don't know what Jump to Cursor does: it lets you move program execution to a new location without executing any of the source code in between.

Comment: As I understand this command is not available for all languages. e.g. nodejs/golang/etc.

Comment: @YuryKozlov True. It is an alias for "Jump to Cursor" introduced in 1.36: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/723adc3cdf3afca7f7cea071c03d86dc02736c2c/release-notes/v1_36.md#jump-to-cursor. Initially only for C#. Cpp followed quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Install the vsc extension of the link below.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ntoskrnl7.cxx-set-next-statement-extension

It works well in cppvsdbg (vscode-cpptools -OpenDebugAD7).

However, GDB requires the following VSC extension to be installed.
https://github.com/ntoskrnl7/code-debug/tree/support_gdb_goto_request

enjoy :)

Comment: This is just for C/C++. Is there something for python